# Updating edition of ebooks purchased from Google Play Books

Tags: ebook-management, google-play-books, download

I've recently purchased an ebook from Google Play Books. It is an engineering book, so it's obvious that it frequently keeps updating to next editions.

My question is that, can we update a book purchased from Google Play Books to next edition and whether it will procure any additional charges?

Answer (score 1):

In paper books editions have new edits and other editions so they are a new published book.

The same thing is true with eBooks and new edition will require you to buy a new copy of that edition.

However with an eBook the publishers can updated the ebook and some do to fix typos and other errors. Then you just need to redownload them.

I am sure that there will be some examples of larger changes being made to the original and just need to be downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

If they republish their e-book as the next edition, then it will be seen as a new e-book, so you will have to purchase it.